# Telegraf interval varies too much with modbus inputs to influxdb

Tags: modbus-tcp, influxdb-2, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

I am reading data from a modbus device with telegraf plugin and I would like "as close as it can get" interval of 500ms. Telegraf plugin writes inputs to influxdb.

Am I having a wrong tool or am I not using it correctly?
It does not seem to mater too much if I read one or several registers.

```
[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "500ms"
  round_interval = false
  metric_batch_size = 100
  metric_buffer_limit = 1000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  collection_offset = "500ms"
  flush_interval = "1s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = "1ms"
  debug = true
  logfile = "loki.txt"

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
   urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
   token = "atoken"
   organization = "org"
   bucket = "modbus"

 [[inputs.modbus]]

   name = "Device"
   slave_id = 1
   timeout = "1s"
 busy_retries_wait = "100ms"

   controller = "tcp://192.168.1.103:8899"

transmission_mode = "TCP"

    configuration_type = "request"
    optimization = "max_insert"

 optimization_max_register_fill = 100

  [[inputs.modbus.request]]

    slave_id = 1
    byte_order = "CDAB"
    register = "holding"
    fields = [

      { address=82, name="energy",        type="FLOAT32",   scale=1.0},
      
      ]

    [inputs.modbus.request.tags]
      group = "energy_group"
```

This is what I get:

[image: output from influxdb]

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

Telegraf runs as a single process to poll each of it's available plugins, [if any plugin fails or delays, it interrupts the rest plugins](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/telegraf-best-practices/). That is why you see those interval varies especially when you run with multiple plugins.

### Solution 1 - Run a dedicated telegraf for each Modbus bus

As the official best practice document recommended, you can run multiple telegraf instances.

### Solution 2 - Use Modbus-to-MQTT gateway (Recommended)

Modbus is master-slave architecture, which is slow and usually blocking communication, while MQTT is event-based and lightweight, now becomes a very popular protocol to integrate with modern IoT systems, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399492/difference-between-mqtt-and-modbus-protocol/70246477#70246477) for a detail comparision.
Use a tool like [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll), you can easily forward Modbus data to MQTT broker and use [MQTT Consumer Input Plugin](https://www.influxdata.com/integration/mqtt-telegraf-consumer/) to integrate with telegraf.

Comment: 1) I had only one plugin running. I made few tests with python. One of them was Backgroundscheduler from apscheduler. Problem does not modbus. It is just pretty hard to get 500ms interval without digging deep to hardware with a pc. I can not drop out modbus. That is the protocol of the device I. I tried modpoll. Interval of one second was the minimun (I think) and it was even worse what came for keeping a strickt interval. For now my weapon of choice is apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler.

Comment: To keep millisecond level accuracy strictly, a dedicated RTOS would be a more appropriate choice. btw, modpoll can support interval lower than 1s.